# Copy Multiple Ranges to New Workbook on Button Click

Tags: excel, vba, union

Operation is: user clicks an "export" button, and two predefined ranges copy into a new workbook.

This code works. I tried everything from defining multiple ranges, to using Union. All the explanations on this site are so complicated I cannot understand how to apply it. I believe from what I've read, I have to copy each range individually.

I have range A1:F54
I also have range G12:T54
The way they paste is the same position as original sheet.

My code copies, format and all, with one range.

Is there a way to copy format, spacing etc. but exclude formulas? I can't find anything besides paste value (which corrupts format).

```vb
Sub Button2_Click()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:F54").Copy
    
    Workbooks.Add
    
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Range("A1")
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub CopyValuesFormats()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Copy values and formats of range A1:F54
    wsSource.Range("A1:F54").Copy
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range G12:T54
    wsSource.Range("G12:T54").Copy
    wsDest.Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: you are a God. PERFECT, and you wrote it simple enough I can now build off it for different scenarios. <3

Comment: Doesn't seem to be copying over the format (column width). Working on that now.

Comment: @CL `wsDest.Columns("G:T").AutoFit` and `wsDest.Columns("A:F").AutoFit`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ExportButton()
    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
    Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("RFQ FORM INT")
    
    Set wbDest = Workbooks.Add
    Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    'Copy values and formats of range A1:F54
    wsSource.Range("A1:F54").Copy
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsDest.Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    'Copy values and formats of range G12:T54
    wsSource.Range("G12:T54").Copy
    wsDest.Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    wsDest.Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    wsDest.Range("G12").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```